# Persistent and transient EMR equivalent clusters in azure and HDInsight

Tags: azure, amazon-emr, azure-hdinsight

I wanted to know if I create an HDInsight cluster on Azure is that fully reliable to work on. For example, I don't want to see after a while one of node is wiped out or deleted and I lose my data.

I know we would have two types of cluster on EMR like transient and persistent but I still have doubt even the persistent cluster could at some point lose nodes data.

Does this happen to Azure HDInsight as well? I would like to know opinion from those guys who have experiences on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Azure HDInsight clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-overview) are similar to Persistent clusters in EMR.

> [On-demand HDInsight Hadoop clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-adf) are similar to transient clusters in EMR.

AWS to Azure services comparison:

[image]

Azure HDInsight follows a strong separation of compute and storage-- as such the recommendation is to store your data either in Azure Storage blobs and Azure Data Lake Store, or a combination of the two. Both provide an HDFS compatible file system that persists data even if the cluster is deleted.

The benefit of this approach is:

- The data is persistent, even after you delete your HDInsight cluster.
  This means it will also be available without any data transfer effort
  should you deploy a new cluster to perform additional processing.
- The costs for storing your data are predominalty driven by the volume of
  data stored and tranferred, which can be signficantly less than the
  costs for running a cluster.
- The data is available for multiple clusters to act upon.

[image]

For more details, refer [Azure Storage overview in HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/overview-azure-storage) and [Use Azure storage with Azure HDInsight clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage)